# Recommended file / filetype for importing online data to SQLite database on Android device

Tags: java, android, import

I use PHP to access my database and generate an XML file online.  My android app then gets that XML file, parses it, and inserts the data into a SQLite database.

This works just fine but is INSANELY slow.  We have an iOS app and an Android App both doing the same thing... the android app takes 7-10 seconds every time the user wants refreshed data,  while the iOS app only takes 2-3 seconds at most.

There aren't a lot of records - 30-50 on average.  There is a lot of content - some large articles, and each with 2-10 photos (I'm not downloading the photos - just importing their url, size...etc)

I followed an example on how to use Sax to import my XML (supposedly the fastest way).

**TLDR:**
Is there a better way I can format my data to make it MUCH quicker than how I'm doing it now?  CSV?  Use PHP to generate SQLite Insert statements?  What is the "norm" and/or "best" for this?

---

**Edit:**
The more I read, the more it sounds like the difference between JSON and XML are miniscule, and can even be faster with XML if it's large data (like articles) instead of JSON.  Not sure this is correct, just details from further reading.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `JSON` instead of `XML` i think it might be a lot faster to work with that. It is supported on Android and as far as I know iOS can handle it as well.

Comment: While I certainly might try JSON if that's what's norm/good, I'm looking for more than "I THINK it MIGHT be a lot faster." :)  Can JSON handle large articles of text with strange characters...etc?  (I've only used json for small amounts of data)

Comment: Yes, it supports large amounts of data, and this is the common format for the kind of thing you are doing.

Comment: for JSON, use the jackson parser.  its faster than the default stuff android gives you.  http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **XML** or **JSON**,  look into Google's **Protobuf** :

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

since you are on PHP, you will need to find an implementation that works for you, here is a list :

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns

Going forward, this will be a very nice way to transfer and marshall data around.  Please let us know if this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is some mark-up in the XML, and according to that doc "protocol buffers would not be a good way to model a text-based document with markup (e.g. HTML)" :(  Shoot - was hoping this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used to create a SQLite db file and gzip it, then unzip it on device and use that directly. (Not a good way for sure)

For later data updates I used json to transfer data.  JSON can surely handle large articles, but if you prefer you can just put urls to the articles in JSON and fetch them in subsequent transfers.

Comment: I'm confused... are you suggesting that gzip way or saying it's not good?  The later updates thing doesn't work, as they should be able to read articles while offline if necessary.

Comment: I felt transferring entire SQLite DB was not a good way to do thing after doing it for about 6 months in production... Some unwanted junk might sneak in and some value that are device-dependent needs to be set separately anyway.  I end up just serving everything on-the-fly with a real backend service.

Comment: If your client app simply come once and fetch the data once, you can pack your sqlite db and gzip and transfer it without worrying about updates. If your client app will update its data after the initial transfer, then you can consider using JSON (which you can put your articles inline after escaping, or the update process can parse the json, extract URL and fetch URLs)

Comment: I'm confused as to why you've answered my question with something you don't recommend doing.  (the other half of which has already been suggested in an answer)

Comment: I answered it because to me it is the fastest way without having to deal with generating sql insert statements in PHP and send it out.  I say not a good way because that was what I felt after using the method for 6 months in production and saw user complaining about strange behaviors as well as maintenance overhead.

Comment: But you're suggesting an answer that you yourself think is a bad idea to use.